# Establishing trust between IdentityServers

Tags: identityserver3

Any idea how to establish trust between identityserver? (Similar to ADFS trust configuration)? my scenario is like this:

**For example:**

- App1 trusts Idsvr1
- App2 trusts idsvr2

App1 makes request to App2 with App1 token. But App2 does not understand App1 token (since it is issued by idsvr1). So App2 redirects App1 request to Idsvr2. Now Idsvr2 sees the token, which was issued by Idsvr1, and since Idsvr2 trusts Idsvr1, Idsvr2 reissues its token by including the claims from idsvr1 token and return the request to App2. Now since App2 has token from its trusted IdentityServer, it will accept the token and serve the request.

So this would require a trust establishment between IdentityServers.

Answer (score 0):

In IdentityServer you can configure the external IdPs you want to trust for front-channel authentication: https://identityserver.github.io/Documentation/docsv2/configuration/identityProviders.html

Comment: So if I add the following code to Idsvr2 startup.cs file ConfigureIdentityProviders method, my scenario described above will work?  'code'   var idsrvOptions = new IdentityServerOptions
            {
                SiteName = "https://myserver/idsvr2",
                SigningCertificate = Cert.Load(),

                AuthenticationOptions = new AuthenticationOptions
                {
                    IdentityProviders = ConfigureIdentityProviders
                }
            };
            app.UseIdentityServer(idsrvOptions);

Comment: Check the samples we have on github.

Comment: @BrockAllen, could you point me to the particular sample you were talking about? I couldn't find any sample were you were setting up a trust configuration between 2 IdentityServers.